# Converting a nested dictionary to a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am looking to convert specific values from a nested dictionary to a string. I am trying to print the first name values.

I have tried

```
str(firstname)
```

but it only prints the `firstname` from the first nested dictionary `[0]`.

I’m looking for the output to be similar to

```
Jerry, Tina, Joe
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post reproducible example. Tour on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can help you making a better question.

Comment: Hey @Tara, can you provide example data like what does your current dictionary look like.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the dict you are using is a bit ambiguous, so this may not be exactly what you are looking for. I took a guess at what was going on :)

Here is what I put together:

```
nestedDict = {"FirstNames": ["Jerry", "Tina", "Joe"],
                "LastNames": ["Smith", "Grey", "Johnson"]}

result = ", ".join(nestedDict["FirstNames"])
```

The output is:

```
Jerry, Tina, Joe
```

If possible, are you able to show the dict you are working with?